# Dropbox: Download Image from a Public URL

Tags: c#, dropbox

I am trying to downlead a file form a shared Dropbox location.
I have been given a URL form a client and URL is public.
for example

```
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/cr9zwyye5bz573ix4sjos/801NMSV621R-M570_1.jpg?rlkey=cupnu908llx3h2vzmmec97z9z&dl=0
```

I was excepting a normal httpclient would be able to do the job but it is not working.

```
public static async Task DownloadFile(string url, string saveAs)
{
     using (var client = GetHttpClient())
     {
          await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, saveAs);
     }
}
```

I can download the image but when I open it, I see following message.

[image]

I have URL of hundreds of images and I can't download them manually form the browser.

Comment: Change `dl=0` to `dl=1`

Comment: Works for me.  How large is the file you get?  Should be 2,901,154 bytes.

Comment: Looks like changing the dl=0 to dl=1 is working, I will try with few more images now.

Comment: For reference, you can find the documentation for that URL parameter here: https://help.dropbox.com/share/force-download